# Is it strong enough to braze stainless steel tubings with silver?

Tags: steel, diy, framebuilding

I was told that you could not braze stainless steel tubing with brass as you would with non-stainless ones. And you should use 56% silver instead? Isn't silver too weak to braze tubes together? I know you should only braze lugs or braze-ons with silver. Then what fiiller should I use to braze stainless tubings?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to braze stainless steel tubings with silver, but it requires a specific process and set of conditions to achieve a strong, reliable joint. Here are the general steps for brazing stainless steel with silver:

Clean the surfaces of the stainless steel tubings to be joined. This is a critical step as any contaminants on the surface can weaken the bond or prevent the brazing process from occurring properly.

Preheat the stainless steel tubings to the proper temperature. This temperature will depend on the specific type of stainless steel you are using and the size of the tubings.

Apply the silver brazing alloy to the joint. This can be done using a brazing rod or a pre-mixed brazing paste.

Use a torch to heat the joint until the brazing alloy melts and flows into the joint. The torch should be moved around the joint to ensure that the alloy is evenly distributed.

Allow the joint to cool slowly to room temperature. This helps to prevent cracking or other stress on the joint.

It is important to note that brazing stainless steel with silver requires a high level of skill and expertise, as the process involves working with high temperatures and materials that can be difficult to braze. If you are not familiar with the process or do not have the necessary equipment and materials, it is recommended that you seek the assistance of a professional brazing service.